# JpaRepository save() action, immediately followed by a findById() call from a separated thread ends in not found item

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using a JpaRepository to store an object.

For those of you like to see coding...

```
    protected synchronized void saveAndPublish(CommandEvent inCommandEvent) {
      commandEventRepository.save(inCommandEvent);
      CommandEventDTO commandEventDTO = commandEventMapper.toDTO(inCommandEvent);
      publishCommandEvent(commandEventDTO);//publishes to a queue
    }

    protected synchronized Optional<CommandEvent> getStored(Long id) {
      return commandEventRepository.findById(id);
    }
```

The ID of the object that I store in the repository is null, but after the save() it assigned and copied by the mapper to correctly to the DTO. This I can see by printing the DTO object before calling publishCommandEvent().

The publish method puts this DTO in a queue that is read by another process (**another thread**) that sends back and acknowledge message. All this happening within time ranges of typically 50ms. When this ack message is received and we try to retrieve the initial CommandEvent, the Optional is empty...

My question here, is: What am I doing wrong?

Nothing of what I have tried works...

1. Using 'saveAndFlush' instead of 'save'
2. Since both methods are synchronized, I have tried adding a sleep after the publish.
3. Setting the database explicitly to autocommit = true

Nothing of this worked. If upon calling getStored I print all the objects in the repository, it is not there.

Interestingly if later in time, I send a 2nd CommandEvent and I inspect the repository, the 1st CommandEvent is there...

Comment: There is some important context missing from the question: how and where are you managing transactions and EntityManager sessions? The behavior you're seeing is almost certainly related to when the session closes and the transaction commits. To give a complete, concrete answer, seeing what you're currently doing with transactions is important.

Comment: Can you please share me sample project on github or somewhere else?